# Complement is connected iff Connected components are Simply Connected

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis

Let $G$ be an open subset of $\mathbb{C}$. Prove that $(\mathbb{C}\cup \{ \infty\})-G$ is connected if and only if every connected component of $G$ is simply connected.

Comment: Intuitively it holds, but I am stuck on both directions. 
For the straight one if we take a connected component of G, say H, and suppose that it is not simply connected , then $\overline C-H$ is not connected. Thus $\overline C-H$ is written as a union of two closed disjoint nonempty sets K and L. From this we should derive absurdity...

Comment: [Linked](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2415064/bounded-components-of-complement-of-bounded-planar-domain-are-simply-connected).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the connected open set $H \subset \mathbb C$ is not simply connected, there is a simple closed curve $C$ in $H$ that is not homotopic to a point in $H$.  Therefore there must be points inside $C$ that is not in $H$.  Such a point and $\infty$ are in different connected components of $({\mathbb C} \cup \{\infty\} - G$.

Comment: Thank you, but I cannot make it clear how exactly this is of help.

Comment: @Dimitris: He did one direction for you (by contrapositive).