# A domain on a sphere is simply connected if and only if its complement is connected

Tags: general-topology, riemann-sphere

I think the statement that a domain (open connected set) in a sphere is simply connected if and only if its complement is connected is a standard result. But how can one prove it? Is it possible to prove this without algebraic topology?

Comment: Note that by puncturing the sphere, you can essentially consider the same problem for (bounded) open sets in the plane.

Comment: Only if? if you cut out two disks the remaining piece is connected...

Comment: @user68061 The remaining piece is not simply connected.

Comment: Maybe your question is a particular case of [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/330479/complement-is-connected-iff-connected-components-are-simply-connected?rq=1)